# Не правильное тело запроса axios.post

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть сервер на котором хранится база данных. Через постман делаю POST и в `body` указываю тип данных `json`, делаю запись типа `"name":"John", "password":"123"`и все нормально, работает как надо. Но когда использую axios.post, то тело запроса идет на сервер как пустое, тоесть создается объект с произвольным id и пустыми полями. Вот сам метод:

```
postPerson: function() {
      const url = 'http://localhost:8080/api/names/users'
      axios.post(url, {
        body: this.new_person,
        dataType: 'json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'localhost:8080',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE'
      })
        .then(response => { this.info = response.data })
    }
```

Вот то что ложу в `body`:

```
new_person: {
        id: 'Jonny',
        Email: '@asd',
        password: '123',
        old: '22'
      }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В [документации](https://github.com/axios/axios) сказано, что при 'PUT', 'POST' и 'PATCH' запросах, необходимо использовать следующую структуру запроса: `axios.post(url, data, options)`

Таким образом, Ваш запрос должен выглядеть так:

```
postPerson: function() {
      const url = 'http://localhost:8080/api/names/users'
      axios.post(url, this.user_person, {
        dataType: 'json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'localhost:8080',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE'
      })
        .then(response => { this.info = response.data })
    }
```